# Elfinder with Greek filenames

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, elfinder

I am trying to use elFinder in my Yii application. The problem arises when I upload files with Greek names to the server. While I see those files correctly rendered on elFilnder browser when i go to physical directory, where the files are stored, I see file-names with "Chinese" symbols. So basically elFinder renames those files, something I don't need at all. 
Also, I've noticed that if I upload manually files with greek names elFinder wont render them at all.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should look in the controler where the file is saved. If you extracted elFilnder in your extension folder you look in sine the files and paste the code of the controler relative to saving the file.

Comment: Hi, I am using Yii ezzelfinder extension. ezzelfinder is located in extension folder. I only have one controller "AdminController" with the following code : ublic function actions()
      {
          return array(
              'fileUploaderConnector' => "ext.ezzeelfinder.ElFinderConnectorAction",
          );
      }